# What resource/attribute to add to allow unauthenticated access to my cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, terraform, google-cloud-functions

I deployed my cloud function on GCP with the terraform code. But by default, the function's access level is authenticated. So when I try to invoke that function through the URL provided by GCP, I get an error that says

> Error: Forbidden
> Your client does not have permission to get URL /getAllEmployees from this server.

Below is my terraform code

```
provider "google" {
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = var.region
  credentials = "../tf-key.json"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "${var.project_id}-bucket1"
  location = var.region
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "source_code" {
  name   = "objects"
  bucket = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems-bucket1"
  source = "D:/gcf-terraform/gcf-1.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_binding" "default" {
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.name
  role           = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  members        = ["allUsers"]
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  name        = "getAllEmployees"
  location    = "us-central1"
  description = "Retrieve all employees."

  build_config {
    runtime     = "go121"
    entry_point = "GetAllEmployees"

    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems-bucket1"
        object = "objects"
      }
    }
  }
  service_config {
    min_instance_count             = 1
    max_instance_count             = 10
    available_memory               = "128Mi"
    timeout_seconds                = 120
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = false
    service_account_email          = "terraform-gcf@terraform-cloud-functions-ems.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}
```

What attribute or resource should I add to my terraform code to deploy my function that will allow unauthenticated access to my cloud function?

I was trying to invoke my cloud function and was expecting the successful invocation but it resulted in an error that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Because Cloud Functions gen2 [runs on top of Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#new-in-2nd-gen), you can see that [the Cloud Functions Invoker role](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles) does not include the Cloud Run invoker permission, but the other role yes.

I don't know if it's normal or a mistake from Google Cloud, but you have to add the run.invoker role to All Users to make your gen2 Cloud Functions working without authentication.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_binding" "default-cloudrun" {
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.name
  role           = "roles/run.invoker"
  members        = ["allUsers"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Key Point:**

- **Assigning Roles for Broad Access:** Ensure that the role `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` is assigned to `allUsers`. This grants universal access to invoke the cloud function.

**Important Considerations:**

1. **Service Account Email Usage:** You're using a new service account email specifically for this function.
2. **Permission Verification:** Confirm that your terraform ADC permission has the necessary permissions to create or edit Cloud Functions. (**gcloud auth default-application login**)

   ## cloud function code

   resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "hello_function" {
   name                = var.func_name
   description         = "An hello Cloud Function"
   runtime             = "python39"
   available_memory_mb = 256
   timeout             = 60

   source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.cloud_function_bucket.name
   source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name

   trigger_http = true
   entry_point  = "handler"

   environment_variables = {
   FOO = "bar"
   }

   labels = {
   env = "dev"
   }
   depends_on = [
   google_storage_bucket.cloud_function_bucket,
   google_storage_bucket_object.archive
   ]
   }

   ## IAM all access

   resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "invoker" {
   project        = google_cloudfunctions_function.hello_function.project
   region         = google_cloudfunctions_function.hello_function.region
   cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.hello_function.name

   role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
   member = "allUsers"
   }

[Codebase refer](https://%20https://github.com/qwedsazxc78/Terraform-from-zero-to-hero-10-Lab-GCP-Infrastucture-as-Code/blob/main/Chap4-GCP%E9%9B%B2%E7%AB%AF%E8%88%87IAC%E6%9E%B6%E6%A7%8B%E5%AF%A6%E6%88%B0/Ch4.1-4.5/Ch4.5.3-GCP-%E7%84%A1%E4%BC%BA%E6%9C%8D%E5%99%A8%E6%9C%8D%E5%8B%99-%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8Terraform%E5%89%B5%E5%BB%BACloud-Function/2-main.tf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).